# basic ruby recursion: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby, recursion

I imagine it's due to an infinite recursion. What am I doing wrong? My goal is to find the smallest number that is evenly divisible by numbers 1-20.

```
def smallest(n, count)
  (2..n).each do |num|
    if count % num != 0
      count += 1
      smallest(n, count)
    end
  end
  return count 
end

puts smallest(20, count=20)
```

Comment: err... where are you expecting this recursion to terminate? `count` will keep growing...

Comment: I thought it would terminate at the return statement. It would only reach the return statement if every number divides equally in the enumerable. Is that logic wrong?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Any tips on making the script work with the least number of changes?

Comment: Finding LCM of 1 to 20 seems to have high time complexity - besides recursion may not be a good choice of technique

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that do you need recursion in this example?
Try your code without invoking `smallest(n, count)`.

By the way- this algorithm finds the number which isn't evenly divisible by numbers 1-20.

Comment: It will work fine. You wanted to invoke this function inside loop (block), but in every `if` you increased counter, which made this task impossible to terminate.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Any tips on making the script work with the least number of changes?

Comment: Just use your code without `smallest` invoking in loop. Delete this line and run again.